# c++ source code to exe

Tags: c++

Is it possible to convert c++ source code to exe file...if yes please let me know the open source software which i can use for the same.

Comment: Sure!  You pay me $1000 to do it.  I will perform some magical incantations and your code will be transformed.  NOTE:  I only guarantee success if your code is compilable with a standard compliant C++ compiler and I do not make any statement or guarantee about the usability of the resulting transformation, only that it will be an exe (AND it will be in EXE format, not just renamed).

Comment: I'll lowball the bidding and do it for $600US.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use GNU C++ compiler: http://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: i want to compile my program from dos emulator...and for that my program needs to be in executable format...thats why i want to convert my source code to exe file

Comment: OK; you're still looking for a compiler.

Comment: @aoss You don't need to compile it in dos to make the executable run in dos.

Comment: People still use DOS?  I thought we'd hunted down all those responsible and those still using it, and executed them all by firing squad.

Answer (score 4):

[Detailed list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C.2FC.2B.2B_compilers)

[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is recommended. [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) for Windows port.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for an open-source C++ compiler. A compiler (e.g. [GNU](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) is exactly what you want to have: "Transforming" C++ source code to a binary executable file. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a compiler, such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Answer (score 2):

They're right, you don't need to compile your program in DOS to run the .exe file in DOS.  I use jGrasp for my C++ development.

[Here](http://www.jgrasp.org/) is the link to download jGrasp (Click "Download jGrasp" on the right of the screen).

Some like DevC++, in which case [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dev-cpp/files/Binaries/Dev-C%2B%2B%204.9.9.2/devcpp-4.9.9.2_setup.exe/download) is the direct link that should start the download of DevC++.

Regardless of which you choose, you can develop your program in either environment, compile it (which produces your .exe file), then you can run it from within the environment, OR if you'd rather you can run it from the DOS prompt by going into the folder (from within DOS) that contains your project (where the compiler should have produced your .exe file) and typing in "a.exe" then click enter.

This is how you do it if you compiled in jGrasp, I know.  I haven't developed in DevC++, but I assume it is similar, if not the same.

Hope this helps!